# Passing loop values of child window to parent window and vice versa

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a text box named subscriber name.when I double clicked on that text box,a child window should open.In that child window list of subscriber names are shown using while loop of mysql query.My problem is when I double clicked on it ll pass a value as **undefined**.This problems comes due to looping of subscriber names from db table.How can I solve it? Please help me soon.Here my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage(){ 
  opener.document.cash_entry.sub_name.value = document.subscriber.subname.value;
  self.close();
}
</script>
<form>
<?php
$sel=mysql_query("select * from add_ticket");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) { 
  $subscriber=$row['subscriber'];
?>
  <input type="text" name="subid" id="subid" value="<?php echo $subscriber; ?>"
  ondblclick="displaymessage()" readonly="true">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Please take a minute to learn how to format your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not named your form and you named your field differently than in the HTML code and you have more than on element with the same name which makes it an array if more than one

Do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage(fld){ 
  opener.document.cash_entry.sub_name.value = fld.value;
  self.close();
}
</script>
<form>
<?php
$sel=mysql_query("select * from add_ticket");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) { 
  $subscriber=$row['subscriber'];
?>
  <input type="text" name="subname" 
  id="subid<?php echo $subscriber; ?>" 
  value="<?php echo $subscriber; ?>"
  ondblclick="displaymessage(this)" readonly="true">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

by why not

```
  <input type="button" value="<?php echo $subscriber; ?>"
  onclick="displaymessage(this)" >
```

For more than one value, you can do

```
function displaymessage(fld){ 
  var parts = fld.value.split("|");
  opener.document.cash_entry.sub_name.value = parts[0];
  opener.document.cash_entry.sub_id.value = parts[1];
  self.close();
}


  <input type="button" 
  value="<?php echo $subscriber; ?>|<?php echo $subscriberID; ?>"
  onclick="displaymessage(this)" >
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply it works.If I have more than one value to pass means what I have to do?for eg subscriber name and his id.